# How to use javascript to go to previous page after running other code?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, datatables-1.10

I have a reporting website that I maintain. I have it setup so that users can select a row and be taken to a form to edit parts of it. After making the edits the user will click the "Submit" button and then a query is run against the SQL DB to update the record in the DB. I want the page to then go back to the referring page. I know that there's a way to do that with javascript something like `parent.history.go(-1);`, but I don't know how to implement it.

Basically, after the `$sth->execute();` I want something that will send the `parent.history.go(-1);`.

I was trying to use `header('Location:')` but that would only work if they had not done a search on the previous page (or any filtering or ordering). If I could have it just go back to the previous page, or maybe even reload the previous page so that their edits show up too that would be great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `header('Location: '.$url)` along with state saving in jQuery DataTables (since your question is tagged `datatables-1.10`) with [`stateSave`](https://datatables.net/reference/option/stateSave) option.

For example:

```
$('#example').dataTable( {
   stateSave: true
});
```

It will save/restore table sorting, filtering and page so that when the same page is visited again the table will have previous state restored.

Comment: Will the `stateSave` work with server side processing?

Comment: and I'm guessing that the `$newURL` is the URL of the previous page?

Comment: I got this to work. Thanks, I had forgotten about the `stateSave` feature in DataTables.

Comment: @Mike, yes, `$newURL` is the URL of the existing page. Changed it to `$url` to avoid confusion. And yes, `stateSave` should work with server-side processing.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the back method.

```
function goBack() {
    window.history.back();
}
```

Comment: How would I call this though?

Comment: Depends, are you gonna use a button? When a script finishes? When the page loads? There are event listener options for all of those.

Comment: I want it to redirect to the previous page once the `$sth->execute();` is done. There's no button or page load. and this will be included in a PHP file.